# How would I go about creating a constant fly buzzing sound effect?

Tags: beginner

I'm trying to create a basic fly buzzing sound effect from scratch. I need it to be constant (as if the fly is hovering completely still from your position) so that I can affect it later. What would be the best way of going about this? (I'm fairly new to sound design, so please pardon me if it shows)

Comment: Blowing over something placed horizontally between your lips. So far I've tried a rubber band [too heavy, deep] & the cellophane wrapper from a cigarette packet [too light, high]. I'll keep looking...

Comment: @Tetsujin - record the rubberband/cellophane and run the result through a high pass filter - If OP wants movement later on, then they can add panning, volume automation, and maybe a little phasing or chorus to simulate the Doppler effect.